# org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setEntityNotFoundDelegate Error

Tags: hibernate, maven, ejb-3.0

I recently updated hibernate-core to 4.2.0.SP1 version. Following which I get a stack trace as follows -

```
SEVERE: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setEntityNotFoundDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/proxy/EntityNotFoundDelegate;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.setEntityNotFoundDelegate(Lorg/hibernate/proxy/EntityNotFoundDelegate;)V
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<init>(Ejb3Configuration.java:173)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:129)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:105)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer.deploy(GlassFishContainer.java:202)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Hibernate-core were you previously using? Could it be that an older version of Hibernate is being added to your classpath via a transitive dependency (when you execute `mvn dependency:tree` what versions of Hibernate are listed?)

Comment: Hibernate-core was not being used previously.

Comment: what were you using previously? (you state in the question that you "recently updated")

Also what does `mvn dependency:tree` show?

Comment: My bad. I updated pom.xml to include hibernate-core
mvn dependency:tree shows the 4.2.0.SP1 version for hibernate-core

Comment: Are any other versions of Hibernate dependencies (i.e. hibernate-annotations etc) listed ?

Comment: hibernate-jpa-2.0-api - 1.0.1.Final. hibernate-commons-annotations - 4.0.1.Final. hibernate-entitymanager - 4.2.0.SP1. hibernate-validator - 4.2.0.Final.

Comment: My presumption is that this is a classpath issue. For whatever reason the version of `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` that it is using does not contain the required method - hence I asked about all versions of Hibernate dependencies (including those that are transitive). The ones you have listed seem okay, so at the moment I am not sure what the issue is. If possible it would be great if you could include your pom in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot DB5. I found out the issue and now it's been solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue was related to the hibernate jar already present. 
So if the hibernate-core jar exists, the hibernate jar is not required.

I removed the hibernate jar and now all works well !

(Hope it is useful to someone having the same issue)